# SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Tags: solidity

Hi I am trying to deploy a contract but keep getting this error. I am new to solidity.

I am running the cmd node deploy.js

**error message**

const interface = JSON.parse(compile).contracts["lottery.sol"].Lottery.abi;
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse ()
at Object. (C:\Users\LG\OneDrive\Desktop\Solidity\lottery\truffle-smart-contract\deploy.js:5:24)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable [] public players;
    
    function Start_Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, now, players)));
    }
    
    function pickWinner() public restricted {   
        address payable winner = players[random() % players.length];

        winner.transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }
    
    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
    
}
```

Deploy.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compile = require('./compile');
const interface = JSON.parse(compile).contracts["lottery.sol"].Lottery.abi;
const bytecode = JSON.parse(compile).contracts["Inbox.sol"].Lottery.evm.bytecode.object;


const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '<mnemonic phrases>',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<xxxxxxxxx>'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from accounts', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
        .deploy({data: '0x' + bytecode})
        .send({from: accounts[0]});
    
    console.log(interface);
    console.log('Contract deployed to', results.options.address);
};
```

compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const lotteryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(lotteryPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'lottery.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}; 

module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/owanhunte/ethereum-solidity-course-updated-code/tree/main/inbox

You can find the updated and working code here !

Answer (score 0):

This part is suspicious.
["Inbox.sol"].Lottery

You read Inbox.sol, why do I access "Lottery" instead of "Inbox"?

Comment: yeah. @Ming you can confirm the interface and bytecode using `console.log`